# Can I selectively remove .cabal file's `ghc-options` in particular files?

Tags: haskell

I am using

```
ghc-options: -Wall
```

in my .cabal file, and love it....

....except when I hate it.  For instance, I have a `Constants.hs` file that looks like this

```
numDogs=1000
numCats=2000
......
....etc for like 100 lines
```

....and of course `-Wall` complains that I don't give all my types signatures, but changing the file to this

```
numDogs::Int
numDogs=1000

numCats::Int
numCats=2000

....etc
```

really would be stupid.

So, is there a way to turn off ghc-opts on a per file basis.

(I know that I can just leave out the ghc-options from cabal, and put it in each file that I want it in using `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}`, but when I do that, I often forget files altogether, so I'd rather not do it this way)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, `{-# OPTIONS_GHC flag #-}` can take *any* [GHC flag](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.4.1/html/users_guide/flag-reference.html#id3129835), so you can simply use `-w` to disable all warnings. But since you're mostly concerned about the missing signatures for constants, you probably want `-fno-warn-missing-signatures` and `-fno-warn-type-defaults`:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-missing-signatures #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-type-defaults #-}
```

That being said, if you're using a bunch of constants with the same type, you can simply write:

```
numDogs, numCats, numParrots, numFishes, numRats :: Int
```

That also removes the warning, and makes sure that the constants have the appropriate type.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the flags implied by `-Wall` have an inversion `-f-no-*` option that if you apply locally will override the global setting. So for instance in a module that you want not to have toplevel signature you could add:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC  -fno-warn-missing-signatures #-}
```

And this will still endow your module with all the other checks implied by -Wall ( incomplete patterns and whatnot ) but just not missing signatures.

Comment: Thanks!  Too bad I can't split the award, you guys both answered correctly.  I'm giving @Zeta it because he mentioned -fno-warn-type-defaults, but I've upvoted you also.